# Trying to load bitmaps efficiently results in no image being displayed

Tags: java, android, listview, bitmap

So I wanted my app to be able to display images efficiently in a listview to prevent OOM errors. I tried implementing this by converting the images to bitmaps and then set this as a background in a framelayout and then used this xml file as the layout of my listview. However, it does not display anything.

This is the adapter class.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

String [] result;
Context context;
int [] imageId;
String [] peopleId;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
public CustomAdapter(MyMainActivity mainActivity, String[] prgmNameList, int[] prgmImages, String[] peopleImages) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    result=prgmNameList;
    context= mainActivity;
    imageId=prgmImages;
    peopleId=peopleImages;
    inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.
            getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return result.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

public class Holder
{
    FrameLayout frame;
    ImageView pic;
    TextView tv;
    TextView imgPeople;
  }
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Holder holder=new Holder();
    View rowView;
    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.program_list_upcoming, null);
    rowView.setRotation(5);
    holder.frame=(FrameLayout) rowView.findViewById(R.id.frame);
    holder.pic = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.frameBackPic);
    holder.imgPeople=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.peopleImage);
    holder.tv=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    holder.imgPeople.setText(peopleId[position]);
    holder.frame =(FrameLayout) rowView.findViewById(R.id.frame);
    holder.tv.setText(result[position]);

    Bitmap bitmap = decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources.getSystem(), imageId[position],400, 130);
    BitmapDrawable myDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(this.context.getResources(), bitmap);
    holder.pic.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    holder.pic.requestLayout();

    rowView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked " + result[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    return rowView;
}

//This is to convert the imageIDs into a array of small bitmaps
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
                                                     int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);
    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}

//this adjusts the size of the bitmap as its needed accordign to the layout dimentsions
public static int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
        final int halfHeight = (int)(height / 1.5);
        final int halfWidth = (int)(width / 1.5);
        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }
    return inSampleSize;
}
```

}

This is the xml file associated with it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:rotation="5">
<!-- First frame layout is to have the picture underneath everything-->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:background="#a8000000">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/frameBackPic"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <!-- First frame layout is to have the bar-->


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_marginTop="83dp"
        android:background="#b8000000">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/buttonPanel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="14">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_weight="10"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:textColor="#d1d1d1"
                android:textSize="18dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/distance"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/peopleImage"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>


    <!-- Second frame layout is to have the translucent bar acr0ss-->
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="#a8000000">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="17dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttonPanel"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="#7e000000"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp" />
    </FrameLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Any insights on how to fix it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This seems like premature optimization.  What were you doing instead that was causing OOM?

Comment: It isn't premature optimization, this is a common form of OOM.  He just isn't doint it right.  Or doing the Adapter right-  he's always creating new views and never reusing convertView

Comment: If you want  my link i deleted my answer and put link here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35664298/recyclerview-stutters-when-srolling-only-14-images/35664641#35664641

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple problems here.

1)You aren't using listview correct.  Your getView should reuse convertView if not null and only create a new view if it is null.  You aren't.  This makes your code totally inefficient, it isn't recycling at all.

2)Your decode function isn't decoding a bitmap.  Its only decoding the size of the bitmap-  inJustDecodeBounds is set to true.  So you will always return null.

3)You aren't saving the bitmaps in any form of cache.  This means you will decode the bitmap each time getView is called, which will be once per row on every scroll event.  You're actually doing worse than not trying to be efficient at all.

4)You're doing this with resources.  Resources are already inflated into full bitmaps at startup.  This kind of optimization, when done correctly, only applies to image files.

5)You're sticking a bitmap in a drawable from resources.  This is done for you at startup.

If you're using bitmap files or bitmaps downloaded from the net, this is a needed optimization.  With what you're doing, you're actually lowering performance and hurting your app.