# RecyclerView stutters when scrolling only 14 images

Tags: android

I've been trying to create a Recycler View full of Card Views. Currently, I'm using the Recycler View from [this tutorial](https://github.com/tutsplus/Android-CardViewRecyclerView) and loading it with 14 different images. The professional quality images range in size from 134K to 242K.(Down from 8MB - 18MB)

I know that the images may be too big but, I feel there must be some way to get better performance while scrolling. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Edit: The images will be stored on the device. There will probably never be more than 20 of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Picasso library` or `Android Universal Image Loader`

[Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

[Android-Universal-Image-Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

You don't need any `AsyncTask`.Theese 2 library handling image operations in background so you can keep scrolling smoothly. I am using `Picasso` in my project right now. You can add error drawable , temporary placeholder default drawable , and its so simple automatically caching.
Just use one of them in `onBindViewHolder` to bind any image to `imageView`

Comment: I've got Picasso, now. If I use this image, http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png, the scrolling is really fast. If I use 14 different images (stored locally) they don't seemed to be cached when return to the top of the view, from the bottom. When I scroll back up to the top, the image views at the top are blank again and fade into existence. How do I hold on to the images?

Comment: Yasin - I'm now pulling some images from the web to substitute the 14. They cache as expected so, they load and scroll quickly! I'm still wondering how I can cache local images.

Comment: so can you post your final code here. I have 15 different drawable , and i am using too. It will only 1 time loading. If you post your code i will compare it to mine and help you.

Answer (score 1):

Load the images in a separate thread (or AsyncTask).

Comment: Where would i put the AsycTask if the images are local?